# Electron.Net window not opening in blazor server app (.Net 6.0)

Tags: blazor-server-side, electron.net

I am trying to create a new Blazor server application working with Electron.Net on .Net 6.0.

Unlike .Net 5.0 and previous, app configuration and startup code is now done in `Program.cs` class, as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d).

What is unclear to me at this stage is how to convert the required Electron.Net lines in .Net 6.0.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET#programcs), we should add the following lines

```
// -- in Program.cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseElectron(args); // <= THIS LINE
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });

// -- in Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    // Open the Electron-Window here
    Task.Run(async () => await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync());
}
```

Now in .Net 6.0 we have only the `Program.cs` class remaining, so these two lines should be converted to :

```
// -- Program.cs .Net 6.0
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // --- Add electron...
    builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);
    ....
    // -- run the app
    app.Run();
    // --- if running Electron - should window be created here - this way?
    Task.Run(async () => await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync());
}
```

I then run the application as `electronize start /PublishSingleFile false`

Output shows app is running but the Electron window is not showing up. Here the console output:

```
ElectronHostHook handling started...
Invoke electron.cmd - in dir: C:\myProject\obj\Host\node_modules\.bin
electron.cmd "..\..\main.js"

Electron Socket IO Port: 8000
Electron Socket started on port 8000 at 127.0.0.1
ASP.NET Core Port: 8001
stdout: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001

stdout: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

stdout: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\myProject\obj\Host\bin\
```

And navigating in my brower to `https://localhost:5001` shows the running app. As it seems, electron is not running properly despite being started.

Comment: HybridSupport.IsElectronActive is always false for .net6

Answer (score 1):

Think I figured it out. Need all these for it to work.

```
builder.Services.AddElectron();
builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);
if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
{
    var window = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync();
    window.OnClosed += () =>
    {
        Electron.App.Quit();
    };
}
```

Comment: @neggenbe I have the exact same problem but this solution does not work for me. do you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just making clear the main method may NOT be `async`, which leads to this code :

```
// --- Add electron...
builder.Services.AddElectron();
builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);
if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive) {
    // Open the Electron-Window here
    Task.Run(async () => {
        var window = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync();
        window.OnClosed += () => {
        Electron.App.Quit();
      };
    });
}
```